# How to log completeOnTimeout of completable-future?

Tags: java, completable-future

I have a couple of completableFutures, with completeOnTimeout ( and return empty object in this case), for example:

```
return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
        try {
            log.info("#####Start sleeping");
            Thread.sleep(9000);
            log.info("#####Finished sleeping");
        } catch (InterruptedException e){
            log.info("#####Interrupted");
        }

        TestEntity reputationEntity = getTestEntity(destination);
        return getTestDTO(destination, accountId, testEntity);}).completeOnTimeout(new testDTO(), asyncTimeoutMls, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

How do I add log the case of completeOnTimeout?
Later in the code, I combine this c future with another one, by:
`CompletableFuture.allOf(test1ComletableFuture, test2ComletableFuture).join();`
So I would like to know ( and log) when one of this feature completed on timeout.
Something like lambda expression inside of completeOnTimeout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to `completeOnTimeout` implementation, there is no option to specify any code or logging, however it turns out `completeOnTimeout` under the hood just schedules a `.complete()` call via a `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor`. So for me it seems absolutely ok to implement it by yourself. A brief example:

```
private final ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor futureCompleteExecutor = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(1);
```

and then

```
    CompletableFuture<String> completableFuture = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> "executed");

    futureCompleteExecutor.schedule(() -> {
        if (completableFuture.complete("timeouted")) {
            // log
        }
    }, 1, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
```

Extract a method to make usage smoothly. Don't execute blocking or long-running code in a scheduled task. Not a perfect, yet flexible approach.

Answer (score 0):

For future references, I finished using:

```
return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(()->{
        TestEntity testEntity = getTestEntity(destination);
        return getTestDTO(destination, accountId, testEntity);})
            .orTimeout(asyncTimeoutMls, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS).exceptionally(e->{
        log.error("Account id: [{}]. Requested test for destination: {}. Failed on timeout: {}", accountId, destination, e.getMessage());
        return new TestDTO();
    });
```